# How to mock "document" object for testing in Meteor App?

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor

I'm using mocha and chai for testing my Meteor app and have a module that uses the document object. The test is running on the server which of course triggers "document is not defined." What's a good way to mock the document object or to otherwise perform tests with a module that uses the document?

I've tried jsdom, jsdomify, and etc. and I've also tried following the Meteor Guide's testing sections for integration testing and full-app testing but I have become stuck.

Any suggestions or examples of using a package like jsdom with meteor would be much appreciated.

**EDIT - Added an example**

Here's a very small example of what I'm trying to do.  I've chopped it down so as to trigger the error without having you add PhaserJS.  However, since it's a project using PhaserJS which requires pixi and p2, it's a little difficult to tell everything that pixi/p2/Phaser need to do with the document.

**/test/game.test.js**

```
import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import  {Game} from '/imports/game.js';

var assert = chai.assert;

if(Meteor.isClient){
    describe('Game', function () {
        it('can add 2 + 3 and return 5 with addNumbers function.', function () {
            //arrange
            var game = new Game();

            //act
            var result = game.addNumbers(2,3);

            //assert
            assert.equal(result, 5);
        });
    });
}
```

**/imports/docChanger.js**

```
//simulates pixi
(function(){
    var docChanger = {};
    docChanger.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    return docChanger;
}).call(this);
```

**/imports/game.js**

```
import docChanger from '/imports/docChanger.js';

export class Game {
    constructor(){
        this.docChanger = docChanger;
    }

    addNumbers(x,y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

I'm using Meteor 1.4.1 and am using the following packages:

- practicalmeteor:mocha
- practicalmeteor:chai

Comment: Could you post some sample code of how you use `document`? I think the answer kind of depends on whether you modify it, access its properties or call its functions as well as on how client-specific the code is.

Comment: @Waiski thanks for the comment. I've added a tiny example. I don't know all the ways document is being used since there are many lines of code in the PhaserJS/pixi/p2 modules I'm using.  But the example above will trigger the error in the most basic way.  Here's a link to the code for the modules I'm using, pixi.js, p2.js and phaser.js : https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/master/build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only run the tests on the client anyway (as you should, there is no reason to run them on the server) you can simply require the problematic components conditionally in the test file:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var Game = require('/imports/game.js').Game;
  describe( ...
```

Since Meteor 1.3.3, nested import statements are supported as well (like `if (Meteor.isClient) { import {Game} from '/imports/game.js'; ...`) But I don't encourage this since it causes problems with eslint.

If you really, *really* need to run code that uses `document` in your server-side tests, you could create it in the global namespace and mock its methods like this:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  GLOBAL.document = { createElement: () => {} };
}
```

This would allow `document.createElement()` to be called without an error. I can't think of situations where this would be useful though, since code that uses `document` is run on the client anyway, and it should be completely sufficient to test it only on the client as well.

Comment: Thanks @Waiski that was just what I needed to make things click and also to recognize some mistakes I had made.